# Android: Create special RadioButton programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, radio-button, android-radiobutton

I am trying to create a kind of scale view. Therefore I use RadioButtons with the text on top of the RadioButton.

Defining this in my layout file works fine:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Text on top"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Text on top"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Now I only need the **RadioGroup**. I want to create the **RadioButtons** **programmatically** and add them to the RadioGroup.

I tried this code, but it does not work:

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(Context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams rbParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
rb.SetButtonDrawable(null);
rb.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,null, Resources.GetDrawable(Android.Resource.Drawable.ButtonRadio));
rb.Text = "Test";
rb.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
rbParams.Weight = 1;
rb.LayoutParameters = rbParams;
radioGroup.AddView(rb);
```

I think `SetButtonDrawable` and/or `SetCompoundDrawable` are not the same as `android:button` and `android:drawableBottom`.

**EDIT:**
Using just the code, without creating RadioButtons in the `.axml` file, I just get the text "*Test*" without a RadioButton.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Using SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds  I see the RadioButton but the Text is not centered.

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

Okay, with Mike's comments (edited in the code) it shows correctly one radio button

[image]

Now the next problem:

Since i need to add more than 1 radio button i tried a simple loop with the same code above.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(Context);
        ...
        radioGroup.AddView(rb);
   }
```

the problem is, it is still only one RadioButton shown. The only thing that happens is, that there appears a little space between the RadioButton an the text.

[image]

**EDIT 4:**

With `LayoutParams.WrapContent` I am able to show all RadioButtons. But my intension was, that the RadioButtons fill up the RadioGroup. That's why I used `match_parent` as width and thought with `weight=1` each RadioButton will get the same space.

[image]

**EDIT 5:**

Setting the width of the LayoutParameters to 0 does not work inside the loop where i create the RadioButtons. If I do so, there are no Radio Buttons displayed.

What works: 
After creating the RadioButtons in the for-loop I call this code:

```
var count = radioGroup.ChildCount;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var currentRb = radioGroup.GetChildAt(i);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rbParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    rbParams2.Weight = 1;

    currentRb.LayoutParameters = rbParams2;
}
```

My only idea to explain this behavior is, that the RadioGroup does not know how many views it will hold and therefore it can't handle the weight attribute for an element that is just being inflated.

But thank you [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) to find this solution step by step!

Comment: How exactly is the code not working?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Change your call to `SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`.

Comment: okay, i see the Radiobutton now, but the Text is not directly on top of the button. The text is on the left, like it would ignor the GravityFlag.Center

Comment: see screenshot in edit 2

Comment: You need to set the gravity on the `RadioButton` itself, not its `LayoutParams`.

Comment: Thanks this helped, but it leads to the next problem (see edit).

Comment: You want `WrapContent`, not `MatchParent`, for both of the `LayoutParams` arguments. As you have it now, the first `RadioButton` is filling its parent, so it's oversized, and pushing the others out the side.

Comment: That solves the problem that they are not shown. but im trying to fill the RadioGroup with the Buttons, thats why i used match_parent and the weight (see edit)

Comment: Oh, then pass `0` for the first `LayoutParams` argument; then it'll respect the weight.

Comment: see my hopefully last edits :)

Comment: Dunno. Works just fine for me. You could try setting the weight in the `LayoutParams` constructor instead. Add a third argument of `1`.

Comment: Can you show me your current code for the following?
1.Radio button generation 
2.Radio Group Generation

Comment: 1. you can see this code in the question, 2. i do not generate a group programmatically, my layout contains a simple RadioGroup with orientation = horizontal @G.hakim

Comment: I think I understand what the problem is, the problem is that you are not assigning the weight to the individual r-buttons but you are applying it to the group

Comment: I just realized you have a `layout_weight` attribute on the root `LinearLayout` in the layout XML you posted. Is that actually being used? I mean, is that `LinearLayout` inside another `LinearLayout`, and does its width depend on some other `View`(s) beside it? If so, that could be messing the `RadioButton`s' measures, especially if you're generating them before the `LinearLayout` has completely laid itself out.

Comment: yes, exactly, LinearLayout that holds <TextView><LinearLayout><TextView>. Only RadioGroup has weight = 1 that the TextViews are always shown and the RadioGroup takes the left space between the views, and the LInearLayout hold the RadioGroup

Comment: Also, if you have a working solution, please post it as an answer, rather than editing it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution that works for me:**

```
    foreach (var option in options)
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(Context);
        rb.SetButtonDrawable(null);
        rb.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,null,ContextCompat.GetDrawable(Context, Android.Resource.Drawable.ButtonRadio));
        rb.Text = option.Text;
        rb.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
        radioGroup.AddView(rb);
    }

    // Weight für die RBs setzen
    for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.ChildCount; i++)
    {
        var currentRb = radioGroup.GetChildAt(i);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rbParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent) {Weight = 1};
        currentRb.LayoutParameters = rbParams;
    }
```

Simplified RadioGroup in .axml:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/formItemScaleLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/formItemScaleStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/formItemScaleRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/formItemScaleEnd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="End"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OK, if the only thing inside that `LinearLayout` is that `RadioGroup`, then the `LinearLayout` is unnecessary. Get rid of the `LinearLayout`, set the `layout_weight` on the `RadioGroup`, and set its `layout_width` to `0dp`.

Comment: Make sure the `TextView`s' `layout_width`s are both `wrap_content`, too. If that doesn't fix it, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Your code can actually be optimized you are running two loops for no reason

Comment: @MikeM. You are right that my layout can be simplified. But, i still cannot set the radiobutton's layout in the same loop, where they are created. Yet, thanks for the help, I am happy with this solution and can go on with that :)

Comment: Yeah, I can't reproduce your issue, so I have to assume it's some problem with the multiple nested layouts with weights. I guess I do have one more idea: you could try using a `RelativeLayout` instead of the `LinearLayout` that's holding the two `TextView`s and the `RadioGroup`. Then align the `TextView`s to either side of the `RelativeLayout`, and align the `RadioGroup` `toRightOf` the left `TextView`, and `toLeftOf` the right `TextView`. That is, https://drive.google.com/file/d/17lrKCzXykjFzJZZpehhNt7CPT0vQcmLx/view?usp=drivesdk. Last suggestion. Four hours is long enough. :-) Cheers!

Comment: OK, really last thing: whenever you use weights, you always want to set the dimension that corresponds to the parent's orientation to `0dp`. I'd mentioned it above, but just noticed that you still the `layout_width` as `match_parent` on the `RadioGroup`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set the layout params to your radio button. Just add `rb.setLayoutParams(rbParams);` before adding your `rb` to your `radioGroup`